# Excel linebreak after copying text via formula

Tags: excel

I have a formula in Excel 2016 which copies the text of a different excel-sheet to another (`=WENN(Daten!E2=0;"";Daten!E2)`). That text could be long so I would like to make a line break in that cell. I activated line break in the alignment-tab but that does change the line break but not the cell height depending on the content of the cell (Only if I write it directly in the cell). I have also activated at the area cell -> format -> resize cell height automatic. If a reclick the line break button it resizes correct.

Is there a function in Excel 2016 which makes a line break dynamical depending on the content of it?

I hope my problem is clear. Maybe some terms are different because I work on a german version of Excel.

Comment: I also use excel 2016 and Wrap Text seems to do what you want. It adjust the linebreaks to the width of the cel. It does this also when it references to text in another cell. But maybe I don't understand you correctly....

Comment: I just found out that the linebreak is indeed correct but the cell height does not automatic resize. I have edited my original question in this way.